# Preview endpoint REST API gives 403 error

Tags: rest-api, json, previews

I am running a local Wordpress backend (port 8888) with a VueJS frontend (port 8081) that loads data via the json REST API. This works fine. However, when I click a preview link in the backend (for example when I made changes to a page), it opens the frontend in a new tab with some preview params, for example:

```
http://localhost:8081/work/?preview_id=11&preview_nonce=d738b8953f&preview=true
```

Now, I need to use these params to get the preview data via the json REST API, so I add these params to the fetch the preview data:

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/11?preview_id=11&preview_nonce=d738b8953f&preview=true&acf_format=standard
```

However, this call returns a 403 Forbidden error. It must be some authorization problem. Is there a way to get this to work without using JWT auth?

Thanks!

Comment: yes but it would mean using a different form of authentication. If you removed authentication entirely then everyone would be able to preview everything. Note that JWT is not the only way to do headless authentication (or the safest)

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell! I understand entirely removing authentication is no option. What kind of authentication would you suggest and does this mean the user (who is logged in in the backend) has to re-authenticate via the frontend?

Comment: yes, previewing is an authenticated action, wether that authentication is done via JWT or another mechanism, I'd suggest leaving the JWT part out though as recommending an authentication mechanism is outside the scope of your question, unless JWT is already in use for that request and it's still failing anyway